# Understanding parentheses within if statements

Tags: c#

I'm going through some C# coding exercises and have run into some operator logic that's stumped me.

The following line of code evaluates to false:

```
int a = 40, int b = 50;

if (a >= 20 && a <= 30 && (b < 20 || b > 30))
    {
       return a;
    }
```

However, if I remove the brackets from inside the if statement, it evaluates to true.

```
if (a >= 20 && a <= 30 && b < 20 || b > 30)
     {
            return a;
     }
```

Can anyone explain what I'm missing? Given that a isn't between 20 and 30, shouldn't it return false? I don't understand why putting the b portion of the if statement in brackets makes it evaluate to false.

Is it evaluating everything prior to "b > 30" as a single condition?

Comment: Operator precedence determines how expressions are grouped if you don't use parentheses.

Comment: @Sweeper: That only applies when all the operators you mix have equal precedence.  `||` and `&&` do not.  And evaluation order is not what is affected.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yep, you're right, just checked the spec.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. I understand where I went wrong now.

Answer (score 2):

This is all to do with operator precedence.

Just like how `*` are evaluated first before `+` (we say `*` has a higher precedence than `+`), `&&` is evaluated before `||`, [as specified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#operator-precedence-and-associativity).

In the first code snippet, you used brackets to "override" this precedence, making the `||` part evaluate first, just like how you can add parenthesis to the expression `1 + 2 * 3` to make it evaluate to 9 instead of 7.

```
a >= 20 && a <= 30 && (b < 20 || b > 30)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                        this part first
```

which becomes:

```
a >= 20 && a <= 30 && true
^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^
now these parts
```

which becomes:

```
false && false && true
```

resulting in `false`.

In the second example however, there are no parentheses so the expression is evaluated according to the normal precedence rules:

```
a >= 20 && a <= 30 && b < 20 || b > 30
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
This part first
```

Which becomes:

```
false || b > 30
         ^^^^^^
         then this
```

which becomes:

```
false || true
```

resulting in `true`.

Comment: Thank you for this. It finally clicked with me because of your explanation.

Comment: @JamesMacDonald Please consider accepting the answer that you think helped you the most by clicking on that checkmark! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the second part where you have removed the parenthesis, it is now divided into two subparts.

First one being : `a >= 20 && a <= 30 && b < 20` This evaluates to false. 
First one being : `b > 30` This statement evaluates to true.

So at the end you have something like this
`F || T`  from both the statements which should eventually give you true as end result

Comment: Is there an order of precedence with && and ||? 'cause that seems to me to be part of what is happening

Comment: Yes. && Has a higher precedence than || . You are correct :)

Comment: It's like if the expression is  A && B || C then it is regrouped as (A&&B) || C